# Hide <tcdl:condition> markup from outbound Email

Tags: outbound-email, tcdl

I have created a Page to use in `outbound Email`, which contains some  `Target Group conditions` for different `component Presentations`. When I preview the page it look fine as per my requirement. But when I send the page using outbound mail an extra `tcdl:Condition` tag is added in the Email markup ,as below

```
<tcdl:Condition type="TrackingKey" operator="=" negate="false">
    <tcdl:Name>Laptop</tcdl:Name>
    <tcdl:Value>1</tcdl:Value>
</tcdl:Condition>
```

Due to this the `Laptop 1` text is added in the mail content.

Is there any way to hide this text[`<tcdl:Name> & <tcdl:Value>`] from the Email content as these tags are added at the time of sending the mail?

**Update-1**

TBBs added in the Page Template

1. Outbound E-Mail Pre-processing
2. dwt Email TBB [Custom Dreamweaver TBB for PT]
3. Outbound E-Mail Post-processing
4. Default Finish Action

The dream weaver TBB contains the below code snippet

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
    <h1>
      Dear [* Name *] [* Surname *]
     </h1>
     <h4 style="text-align: left; background-color:#FFFFFF; margin-left:2%; padding:0; border:0; font-size:medium; color:#2972CC;" >
      Some promotions for you 
     </h4>
   <!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Components" -->
      <div>@@RenderComponentPresentation()@@</div>
   <!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
  <p>From :</p>
   <img src="@@OutboundEmail_OpenTracking@@" alt="" />
    </body>
 </html>
```

The component Template contains the following TBBs

1. dwt Article TBB [Custom Dreamweaver TBB for CT]
2. Default Finish Action

The dream weaver TBB contains the below code snippet

```
    <div style="width:100%">
    <h1 style="color:green">@@header@@</h1>
         <table>
           <tr style="width:95%">
             <td style="width:30%; vertical-align:text-top"><p>@@description@@</p></td>
             <td style="width:40%; vertical-align:text-top"><a href="@@GetLinkTrackingURL(linkUrl,Component.Metadata.Category)@@"><img src="@@EmbedImage(image)@@" width="200px" height="160px"/></a></td>
           </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please share the names of all of the TBBs that you have added to your template.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: I believe the Default Finish Action should remove that markup again. Are you testing the Mailing or sending it? When sending, it will use the output from the last test -- I'm thinking maybe the TCDL tags were still in there when you last tested it?

Comment: I assume your Default Finish Action TBB still contains the "Cleanup" TBB, right?

Comment: After testing the mail , I am sending it .In my case the test mail also contains the tcdl markup. And yes, the Default Finish Action has the Clean Up TBB.

Comment: That's very strange. I've never seen that. I guess you could try not using the Default Finish Actions at all?

Comment: Its working now !!! After removing the default finish action TBB. Thanks Peter!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is added by the "Target Group Personalization" TBB, which is part of the Default Finish Actions. It's not meant for Mailings but rather for when you are publishing to the web.

The Mailer service will handle the Target Groups for you, so you can just remove the Default Finish Action from your template.